# R - How do document the number of grepl matches based in another data frame?

Tags: regex, r, twitter

This is a rather tricky question indeed. It would be awesome if someone might be able to help me out.

What I'm trying to do is the following. I have data frame in R containing every locality in a given state, scraped from Wikipedia. It looks something like this (top 10 rows). Let's call it `NewHampshire.df`:

```
 Municipality       County Population
1       Acworth     Sullivan        891
2        Albany      Carroll        735
3    Alexandria      Grafton       1613
4    Allenstown    Merrimack       4322
5       Alstead     Cheshire       1937
6         Alton      Belknap       5250
7       Amherst Hillsborough      11201
8       Andover    Merrimack       2371
9        Antrim Hillsborough       2637
10      Ashland      Grafton       2076
```

I've further compiled a new variable called `grep_term`, which combines the values from `Municipality` and `County` into a new, variable that functions as an or-statement, something like this:

```
 Municipality       County Population  grep_term
1       Acworth     Sullivan        891  "Acworth|Sullivan"
2       Albany      Carroll        735   "Albany|Carroll"
```

and so on. Furthermore, I have another dataset, containing self-disclosed locations of 2000 Twitter users. I call it `location.df`, and it looks a bit like this:

```
[1] "London"                     "Orleans village VT USA"     "The World"                 
 [4] "D M V Towson "              "Playa del Sol Solidaridad"  "Beautiful Downtown Burbank"
 [7] NA                           "US"                         "Gaithersburg Md"           
[10] NA                           "California "                "Indy"                      
[13] "Florida"                    "exsnaveen com"              "Houston TX"
```

I want to do two things:

**1: Grepl through every observation in the `location.df` dataset, and save a TRUE or FALSE into a new variable depending on whether the self-disclosed location is part of the list in the first dataset.**

**2: Save the number of matches for a particular line in the `NewHampshire.df` dataset to a new variable. I.e., if there are 4 matches for Acworth in the twitter location dataset, there should be a value "4" for observation 1 in the NewHampshire.df on the newly created "matches" variable**

What I've done so far: I've solved task 1, as follows:

```
for(i in 1:234){
  location.df$isRelevant <- sapply(location.df$location, function(s) grepl(NH_Places[i], s, ignore.case = TRUE))
}
```

How can I solve task 2, ideally in the same for loop?

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code for solving task 1 will write to `location.df$isRelevant` 234 times and only what it wrote last will stay. So, removing the loop and replacing `i` by 234 will give the same result, which is probably not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to task one, you could also use:

```
# location vector to be matched against
loc.vec <- c("Acworth","Hillsborough","California","Amherst","Grafton","Ashland","London")
location.df <- data.frame(location=loc.vec)

# create a 'grep-vector'
places <- paste(paste(NewHampshire$Municipality, NewHampshire$County,
                      sep = "|"), 
                collapse = "|")
# match them against the available locations
location.df$isRelevant <- sapply(location.df$location, 
                                 function(s) grepl(places, s, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

which gives:

```
> location.df
      location isRelevant
1      Acworth       TRUE
2 Hillsborough       TRUE
3   California      FALSE
4      Amherst       TRUE
5      Grafton       TRUE
6      Ashland       TRUE
7       London      FALSE
```

To get the number of matches in the `location.df` with the `grep_term` column, you can use:

```
NewHampshire$n.matches <- sapply(NewHampshire$grep_term, function(x) sum(grepl(x, loc.vec)))
```

gives:

```
> NewHampshire
   Municipality       County Population            grep_term n.matches
1       Acworth     Sullivan        891     Acworth|Sullivan         1
2        Albany      Carroll        735       Albany|Carroll         0
3    Alexandria      Grafton       1613   Alexandria|Grafton         1
4    Allenstown    Merrimack       4322 Allenstown|Merrimack         0
5       Alstead     Cheshire       1937     Alstead|Cheshire         0
6         Alton      Belknap       5250        Alton|Belknap         0
7       Amherst Hillsborough      11201 Amherst|Hillsborough         2
8       Andover    Merrimack       2371    Andover|Merrimack         0
9        Antrim Hillsborough       2637  Antrim|Hillsborough         1
10      Ashland      Grafton       2076      Ashland|Grafton         2
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your answers. I tried your approach to task 1, yet for some reason it gives me a "TRUE" for every value, apart from NA's. How can that be?

Comment: `London
TRUE
2
Orleans village VT USA
TRUE
3
The World
TRUE
4
D M V Towson
TRUE
5
Playa del Sol Solidaridad
TRUE
6
Beautiful Downtown Burbank
TRUE
7
NA
FALSE
8
US
TRUE
9
Gaithersburg Md
TRUE
10
NA
FALSE
11
California
TRUE
12
Indy
TRUE
13
Florida
TRUE
14
exsnaveen com
TRUE
15
Houston TX
TRUE
16
Tweaking
TRUE
17
Phoenix AZ
TRUE
18
Malibu Ca USA
TRUE
19
Hermosa Beach CA
TRUE
20
California USA
TRUE
21
Here
TRUE`

Comment: @nikUoM My first guess would be that all those names are in the other dataframe as well. Because it works in the example I used, it is hard to say what the problem is without the data you are using.

Comment: @nikUoM Could you include example data in your question which illustrates the problem from your comment?